# java.lang.Boolean more than two Instances

Tags: java

I have noticed a really weird behaviour in the Code of the [HiberSAP Project](http://hibersap.sourceforge.net/current/) ([BooleanConverter](http://hibersap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hibersap/tags/hibersap-1.1.0/hibersap-core/src/main/java/org/hibersap/conversion/BooleanConverter.java?revision=449&view=markup) Linenumber 75).

The Problem is that a boolean value is not converted into 'X'. I have debugged the Code and inspected the boolean expression `javaValue == Boolean.TRUE`. This expression is interpreted as false because javaValue is `Boolean.TRUE` and has the ID 36 and Boolean.TRUE has the ID 33 (The ID is shown in the Variables-View of the Eclipse IDE). I can also inspect all Instances of Boolean and indeed, there are four Instances of java.lang.Boolean!!

Could somebody please explain me why this is happening.

---

### EDIT:

Okay, I think my Question isn't precise enough. The field which should be converted is **boolean** and not **java.lang.Boolean**. This must be a Classloader Fault here. In my case the only conversion from boolean to Boolean is done by the JVM. I know every Object comparison should use .equals() (and I fill in a Bug) but in this case it should work as it is. See the following Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        print(true);
    }

}

public static void print(Object value) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This should **NOT** create 1000 java.lang.Boolean Instances. This should **always** use java.lang.Boolean.TRUE! And this is the Strange behaviour of the Code that I couldn't understand.

Maybe this are the side effect of the reflection which is done by Hibersap? But I think this should not be a reason for such a behaviour.

Please, I just want to understand.

Comment: How are you creating the javaValue (the parameter which is passed to the method)?

Comment: If you change the equality check to Boolean.TRUE.equals (javaValue), the comparison will work fine. This is because some genius created a new instance of the TRUE value using "new Boolean" and put that into javaValue. == compares references, being different then, and .equals comares the referenced values.

Comment: The same pitfalls await you for strings, see String interning questions here at SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you're doing `new Boolean(true)` or `new Boolean(false)`, you create a new instance of Boolean, which is, by definition, different from other instances. Objects, except enums, should never be compared with `==`. Use `.equals()` instead. Or, in your case, use `javaValue.booleanValue()`.

Comment: Replace the System.out call by `System.out.println(value == Boolean.TRUE);`, and you'll see that autoboxing does not create new Boolean instances. Anyway, it should not matter. Comparing Boolean instances with == is a bug, and this is what should be fixed. Some other code could be optimized to avoid needless Boolean instantiation, but instantiating a Boolean is not a bug per se.